# WPF Webbrowser invokeScript call external JS function

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf

I have a function defined in a JS file.

Test.js

```
function fillData()
{
    alert("fill");
}
```

I have loaded the js file in html file like this.

Index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST</title>
    </head>
    <script src="./PathToJs/Test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
 <body>
        <h1>Test Page</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am calling this function from c# using webbrowser InvokeScript method.

```
webBrowser.InvokeScript("execScript", new Object[] { "fillData()", "JavaScript" });
```

But the method is not getting called. There is no alert box coming.

If the Javascript method is defined in the HTML itself then fillData() method is getting called.

**Let me know how to call the external JS methods using WPF WebBrowser.InvokeScript method.**

Comment: May be I missed something, but why you need to use `execScript` instead of direct call to your `fillData` with `webBrowser.InvokeScript("fillData", new Object[] { "JavaScript" });` or even simple `webBrowser.InvokeScript("fillData");`?

Comment: @Serg The problem is fillData is defined in a separate JS file and not directly in HTML file. If the fillData is method is present in HTML itself inside the script tag then webBrowser.InvokeScript("fillData"); will work fine.

Comment: Actually, this should work in the same way for in-page and external js code. Does external js file actually loaded in runtime? Please try to add test alert in the global scope of Test.js. Will the alert be shown?

Comment: Are you sure `./PathToJs/Test.js` being copied to the output folder?

Comment: @Serg It seems like there is some error in the js file and it is not loaded properly. That's why it is not able to find the name of the methods defined in the JS file. I will look into it. Thanks for the help.